# How can I get the normal \mathcal font in Pages?

Tags: pages, font, latex

I need to typeset some LaTeX formulas in pages, to make illustrations on a scientific article. In all other LaTeX typesetters when I use `\mathcal{F}` I get this:

[image: Usual mathcal]

Instead on pages I get this

[image]

Can I enter some preamble command in the equation box to obtain the first version of `\mathcal`? Or maybe there is some chan ge in settings?
I have looked [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202501#latexpackages) and [here](http://gva.noekeon.org/blahtexml/blahtexml-0.9-doc.pdf), but I can't find an answer.